# What's the fastest way to select values from columns based on keys in another columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I need a fast way to extract the right values from a pandas dataframe: 
Given a dataframe with (a lot of) data in several named columns and an additional columns whose values only contains names of the other columns, how do I select values from the data-columns with the additional columns as keys?

It's simple to do via an explicit loop, but this is extremely slow with something like .iterrows() directly on the DataFrame. If converting to numpy-arrays, it's faster, but still not fast.  Can I combine methods from pandas to do it even faster?

Example: This is the kind of DataFrame structure, where columns `A` and `B` contain data and column `keys` contains the keys to select from:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'A': [1,2,3,4],
     'B': [5,6,7,8],
     'keys': ['A','B','B','A']},
)
print(df)
```

output:

```
Out[1]: 
   A  B keys
0  1  5    A
1  2  6    B
2  3  7    B
3  4  8    A
```

Now I need some *fast* code that returns a DataFrame like

```
Out[2]: 
   val_keys
0         1
1         6
2         7
3         4
```

I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
tmp = df.melt(id_vars=['keys'], value_vars=['A','B'])
out = tmp.loc[a['keys']==a['variable']]
```

which produces:

```
Out[2]: 
  keys variable  value
0    A        A      1
3    A        A      4
5    B        B      6
6    B        B      7
```

but doesn't have the right order or index. So it's not quite a solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

See if either of these work for you

```
df['val_keys']= np.where(df['keys'] =='A', df['A'],df['B'])
```

or

```
df['val_keys']= np.select([df['keys'] =='A', df['keys'] =='B'], [df['A'],df['B']])
```

No need to specify anything for the code below!

```
def value(row):
    a = row.name
    b = row['keys']
    c = df.loc[a,b]
    return c
df.apply(value, axis=1)
```

Comment: They work for the minimal example, but are not great in the case that there are 20-30 "data" columns (those that I call A and B) instead of just the two.

Comment: Yes, it produces the right output, but it's really slow as it's effectively an explicit for-loop accessing the rows of df, which is not a fast solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filtering then mapping:

```
df_A = df[df['key'].isin(['A'])]
df_B = df[df['key'].isin(['B'])]

A_dict = dict(zip(df_A['key'], df_A['A']))
B_dict = dict(zip(df_B['key'], df_B['B']))

df['val_keys'] = df['key'].map(A_dict)
df['val_keys'] = df['key'].map(B_dict).fillna(df['val_keys'])      # non-exhaustive mapping for the second one
```

Your `df['val_keys']` column will now contain the result as in your val_keys output.

If you want you can just retain that column as in your expected output by:

```
df = df[['val_keys']]
```

Hope this helps :))